# Descent of flatness from algebras to monoids II

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, toric-varieties, semigroups-and-monoids, flatness

This is a follow-up question to [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/253534). There, Benjamin Steinberg showed that a morphism of commutative monoids $u$ need not be flat if the induced morphism of $R$-algebras $R[u]$ is flat for some nonzero commutative ring $R$.

However, I would be happy with such a descent result in a much more specific situation, coming from toric geometry.

Let $V$ be a real vector space of finite dimension, let $N$ be a $\mathbb{Z}$-structure in $V$, and let $M$ be its dual $\mathbb{Z}$-structure. Let $\sigma$ and $\tau$ be sharp $N$-rational polyhedral cones in $V$, i.e., intersections of finitely many $N$-rational hyperplanes in $V$ that do not contain a line, and suppose that $\sigma\subseteq\tau$. (Note that $\sigma$ need not be a face of $\tau$.) Taking dual cones and intersecting them with $M$ yields monoids $\sigma^\vee_M$ and $\tau^\vee_M$ such that $\tau^\vee_M\subseteq\sigma^\vee_M$. Let $u$ denote the corresponding inclusion morphism.

Now, we ask the same question in the aforementioned question:

> Suppose $R[u]$ is flat for some nonzero commutative ring $R$. Can we conclude that $u$ is flat?

Note that in this setting, the monoids $\sigma^\vee_M$ and $\tau^\vee_M$ are rather nice: For example, they are torsionfree, integrally closed and of finite type. And, since $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are supposed to be sharp, Benjamin's example does not work here.

Comment: The monoid extension is flat if and only if the category of elements is filtering. This happens for localization.

Comment: Since your monoids are cancellative I think that flatness is equivalent to if A is the smaller monoid and B the bigger one then bA and b'A intersect for any b,b' in B.